# Yii, how to pass variables to model from controller?

Tags: variables, yii, model, controller

im wondering how to do it, i dont think its the same way about passing variables from controller to views, its just that i need to count columns on the database and i can do it from the controller, but how to pass it to model?.

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'parametro_id' => 'Parametro',
            'variable' =>  'ucfirst($variable)',    
        );
    }
```

variable is the var, it says its not defined, how to do it?

Comment: What you need to pass data on the number of columns in the model? Also you can set not DB attribute of model just `$model->columnsCount = $columnsCount`

Comment: not exactly numbers of the columns, its just that some columns are being created automatically and i have to set attributes for thoses auto-created columns, of course id and name column are not included

Comment: i made it creating a new file that will contain the names of the columns that are being created and i use get_content_file() to get thoses names from the model, thanks anyways for your attention

Answer (score 2):

Yii will automatically generate a label using [`generateAttributeLabel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#generateAttributeLabel-detail) based on the column name in the database if you do not specify one. You do not need to call `ucfirst()` to format your variable.

> By default an attribute label is generated using generateAttributeLabel.
>
> Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#attributeLabels-detail

---

> `generateAttributeLabel()` method:
>
> Generates a user friendly attribute label. This is done by replacing underscores or dashes with blanks and changing the first letter of each word to upper case. For example, 'department_name' or 'DepartmentName' becomes 'Department Name'.

---

Simply remove that line in your labels method to allow Yii to format the name for you:

```
'variable' => 'ucfirst($variable)',
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Declare a variable in model as

```
public $columnCount;
```

Now in controller you can count the model and you can create an object for particular model and later on assign the value to this

```
public function actionColumncount(){
    $model = new modelname();
    $model->columnCount = 5;//Your count operation goes here
    //You may proceed with your proceedings
}
```

Then in model you can access this as

```
$this->columnCount;
```

Hope this would do

Comment: Tried and Tested make a try and then comment