# Yii2-How to access a variable from model to a controller?

Tags: variables, yii, model, controller, yii2

I am working on `yii2`. I have came across a point in which I have to send an email to a person when a meter is installed and it's images are uploaded to the server. Fro this I have already configured the `swift mailer`.

There is a model named `Installations` which have a function which saves all the installation data.

```
public static function saveAll($inputs){
    $coutner = 0;
    $arr_status = [];

    foreach ($inputs as $input) {
        $s = new Installations;
        foreach ((array)$input as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'image_names') {
                if ($s->hasAttribute($key)) {
                    $s->$key = $value;

                }
            }
        }



        $user = Yii::$app->user;

        if (isset($input->auth_key) && Users::find()->where(['auth_key' => $input->auth_key])->exists()) {
            $user = Users::find()->where(['auth_key' => $input->auth_key])->one();
        }


        $s->created_by = $user->id;

        if (Installations::find()->where(['ref_no' => $input->ref_no])->exists()) {
            $arr_status[] = ['install_id' => $input->install_id, 'status' => 2, 'messages' => "Ref # Already exists"];
            continue;
        }
        $s->sync_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s  ');

        if($s->save()){

            if ($s->istallation_status == 'Installed') {

                Meters::change_status_byinstall($s->meter_msn, Meters::$status_titles[4]);
            }
            else if ($s->istallation_status != 'Installed' && $s->comm_status =='Failed')
            {
                Meters::change_status_byinstall($s->meter_msn, Meters::$status_titles[5]);
            }
            $arr_status[] = ['install_id' => $input->install_id, 'status' => 1];
            $coutner++;

            if (isset($input->doc_images_name)) {
                foreach ($input->doc_images_name as $img) {
                    $image = new InstallationImages;
                    $image->image_name = $img->image_name;
                    $image->installation_id = $s->id;
                    $image->save();
                }
            }
            if (isset($input->site_images_name)) {
                foreach ($input->site_images_name as $img2) {
                    $image2 = new InstallationImagesSite;
                    $image2->image_name = $img2->image_name;
                    $image2->installation_id = $s->id;
                    $image2->save();
                }
            }
        }else{
            $arr_status[] = ['install_id' => $input->install_id, 'status' => 0, 'messages' => $s->errors];
        }
        $status = $s->istallation_status;
        $msn = $s->meter_msn;
        $com = $s->comm_status;
        // want to pass these variables to the controller function

    }

    return ['status' => 'OK', 'details' => $arr_status, 'records_saved' => $coutner];

}
```

Now There Is a Controller name `InstallationController`. This controller contains all the `APIs` for my mobile application. Below are two main functions in it

```
public function actionAddnew()
{
    $fp = fopen('debugeeeeeee.txt', 'w+');
    fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    fclose($fp);
    $inputs = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    return Installations::saveAll($inputs);
}

 public function actionSavephoto()
{


    try {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($_FILES as $f) {
            $dd = pathinfo($f['name']);
            if (!isset($dd['extension']) || !in_array($dd['extension'], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
                return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'uploaded_files' => $count, 'message' => 'Invalid File'];
                break;
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($f['tmp_name'], Installations::UPLOAD_FOLDER . $f['name'])) {
                $count++;

                return ['status' => 'OK', 'uploaded_files' => $count];

                break;
            } else {
                return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'uploaded_files' => $count];
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception $x) {
        return ['status' => 'ERROR', 'message' => $x->getMessage()];
    }
}
```

The mobile application will call the `Addnew()` api and after that it will call the `savephoto`. Now I want to pass `$msn`,`$status` and `$com` values from the Model to the controller function `Savephoto`.

For this I have tried to use `session variables` but still I am unable to get by desired result(s).

I have also checked the question [Yii, how to pass variables to model from controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795062/yii-how-to-pass-variables-to-model-from-controller?rq=1)
 but it didn't worked for me.

How can I achieve it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get those values out of `saveAll()` is to return them. Presently, they are defined on an object in $s that is overwritten each loop. The best way to do that seems to be creating an array outside of your `foreach ($inputs...` loop and appending each created `Installations` object.

Return that at the end, and pass it (or just the relevant element from it) into `actionSavephoto()` as a parameter. Then, those values will be accessible of properties of that passed object. This handling will occur in the code that is not pictured which calls `actionAddNew()` and then `actionSavephoto()`

Comment: So should I change the return statement in the model as `return ['status' => 'OK', 'details' => $arr_status, 'records_saved' => $coutner,$msn,$com,$status];`?

Comment: next to your definition of `arr_status` add something like `$installation_objects = [];`, then at the end of the loop save `s` into the array: `$installation_objects[] = $s;` and and return: `return ['status' => 'OK', 'details' => $arr_status, 'records_saved' => $coutner, 'installation_objects' => $installation_objects];`

Comment: In my Installation Controller, in function `Addnew`, the  `$inputs` includes all the installation details. 

Can I do something with that ?

Comment: If there is some way for you to pass that array to `actionSavephoto` then it will accomplish your needs, yes? Can you pass it as a function argument? This stuff is happening in the code that initially called `actionAddnew`, so I can't see the details

Comment: I am doing like this in `savePhoto`, ` $fp = fopen('debugeeeeeee.txt', 'w+');
        fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));
        fclose($fp);
        $inputs = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        $msn = $inputs[0]->meter_msn;
        $status = $inputs[0]->istallation_status;
        $com = $inputs[0]->comm_status;`

Comment: But it shows me error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: That error looks like `$inputs` is not getting defined sometimes. Maybe wrap the assignments in `if (!empty($inputs[0])) { /* do the stuff */ } else { print('DEBUG!'); var_dump($inputs); }` so that you can see what's going on.